# ANOVA and Tukey-HSD across table

Tags: r, anova, tukey

I would like to run a one-way ANOVA followed by a Tukey across each column of a table.
My example table is:

```
DF<-data.frame(A=c(rep("Positive", 3), rep("Negative",3)),
                  B=c(rep(c("Control","Treatment"),3)),
                  Values=c(12,23,12,24,12,34),
                  Values2=c(32,34,65,23,54,23),
                  Values3=c(34,34,56,21,56,21),
                  Values4=c(76,36,87,21,85,23))
```

I would like to run something like:

```
aov(data=DF, formula=Values~A*B)
```

for each single column and then followed by a Tukey.

My first attempt I tried this:

```
avn<-function(x){aov(x, formula = x~A*B)}

t.DF<-apply(aj.fr, 2, avn)
```

and got errors. Can someone suggest how to proceed with this?

Comment: if you change your attempt to `avn <- function(x){aov(x ~ DF$A * DF$B)}; apply(DF[, -(1:2)], 2, avn)` it should work. or `lapply(DF[, -(1:2)], function(x) aov(x ~ DF$A * DF$B))` or `lapply(colnames(DF)[-(1:2)], function(x) aov(reformulate('A * B', x), DF))`

Comment: Thank you very much